# Buffer overflow in certain places only with compiler optimizations turned on

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, compiler-optimization

So I am having an issue where a certain piece of code is giving me this error `*** BUFFER OVERFLOW DETECTED ***` . This only started happening once I turned certain compiler optimization options on (*this isn't my program so I have to use these*). I've narrowed it down to which option it is. I also found a way to stop the buffer overflow, however, I have extremely similar code in another portion of the program that *doesn't* give me the same error when I leave it as is. This is leaving me very confused and very unconfident about my fix so some guidance would be appreciated.

Here are the optimization options from the `makefile`

```
CXXFLAGS+=-Os -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer 
CXXFLAGS+=-fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations
```

I have narrowed it down to the `-O2` flag which starts causing the error.

Here is the function which fails on a buffer overflow at `realpath()` only if the `-O2` flag is specified

```
static std::string getRealTargetPath (std::string baseTarget)
    {
    char nextTargetLink[MAXPATHLEN];
    memset (nextTargetLink, 0, MAXPATHLEN);

    if (realpath (baseTarget.c_str(), nextTargetLink) == NULL)
        return "";
    else
       //etc...
    }
```

The function above will behave as desired if I change `MAXPATHLEN`(size 1024) to `PATH_MAX` (size 4096). Ok, fair enough. But this following snippet of code executes ~20 lines after using the **same** `std::string baseTarget` as before.

```
char realLinkPath[MAXPATHLEN];
memset (realLinkPath, 0, MAXPATHLEN);

do
    {         
    if (realpath (linkPath.c_str(), realLinkPath) != NULL)
        if (strcmp(linkPath.c_str(), realLinkPath) != 0)
            return true;

    size_t eraseFrom = linkPath.rfind('/');
    if (std::string::npos != eraseFrom)
        linkPath.erase(eraseFrom);
    } while ( !linkPath.empty() );
```

In summary even though these two `realpath` functions are using the same `const char* path` variable the first one will fail if the buffer is not `PATH_MAX` length but the second one will not, this all only happens if the `-O2` flag is specified for compilation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: As a user pointed out, I also tagged this as `C` because the program is very old and the core was written in `C` it's preferred that I keep it as C as possible without using *too* many `C++` features

Comment: why do you need to use C api anyways?

Comment: The program is ~20 years old and the core is written in `C` so its preferred that I keep it as 'C' as possible.

Comment: What's MAXPATHLEN ? realpath() documents the 2. parameter must be at least PATH_MAX.

Comment: Do you have the code for `realpath()`?  If not how is `realpath()` declared?

Comment: @nos the docs specify that it will be *up to* `PATH_MAX`. The program already sets an internal limit for paths that is much shorter than this so that length would never be reached because it would be caught much sooner.

Comment: Its not the optimization flag that is causing the buffer overflow -- the flag is just causing it to be detected.  Without the flag, the overflow is still happening, its just not being detected.  The overflow may still be causing the program to produce (subtly) garbage results in other ways.

Comment: @stazima Well that depends on what the actual path is. The path that realpath resolves could still be larger than what you have limited the 1. argument to. (The obvious example is that the path is actually a symlink to a path much deeper in the system, and the non-obvious example could be something causing your buffer overflow). I'm just asking what your MAXPATHLEN is, it could be greater than PATH_MAX, but when the docs says it can be up to PATH_MAX, you need to make it at least PATH_MAX.

Comment: To make the code C code, a single C++ feature is "too much" already. There is no "a little bit pregnant"

Comment: I know this is after the fact, but why oh why don't these API functions have a way of just returning in some way the maximum number of characters that the returned buffer will contain (and not fill in anything)?  Then all of this would be moot.

Comment: @Olaf the root of the problem is a C API, so this is equally relevant to C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the second part has different input, so it happens to work well *by accident*. `realpath()` is a really broken function, even the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) states that (see **BUGS**).

The best you can do ist rework the code so realpath is invoked with a `null` pointer as it's second argument and take care that the allocated buffer you get returned is `free()`d properly

Comment: The inputs aren't different though, they just have different variable names. Whats contained in them is exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, then you'd have to look at the assembler code to really know what's going on, but I bet the root of the problem is `realpath`. Also, allocating `PATH_MAX` bytes on the stack is a particularly *bad idea*, this might be a huge amount.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the accepted answer because I didn't read the bugs section of the man page. I went back and just used the option for `NULL` as `resolved_path` and `free()` later and everything is working now.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `realpath` specifies that the length of `resolved_path` must be at least PATH_MAX.  If the results of `realpath` is a string longer than 1024 bytes, and your buffer is not big enough, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That means that a crash might (as in the first case) or might not (as in the second case) happen.

Comment: The docs specify that it will be *up to* `PATH_MAX`. The program already sets an internal limit for paths that is much shorter than this so that length would never be reached because it would be caught much sooner. Besides, the "real" path is only  35 chars long.